# Autoloader Error after updating to Zend Framework 2.2.5

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, autoloader

As a warning I am not a programmer.  I inherited an application which uses Zend Framework and needs to be updated and I'm trying to do my best here.  I will really appreciate if you can provide detailed information to troubleshoot the issue.

After updating Zend Framework to version 2.2.5 I started getting the error shown below.
I came across this online but I am not sure how to use the examples to correct the error.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.loader.autoloader-factory.html

```
Warning: require_once(/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or   directory in D:\vFabricWS\vfabric-web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs\globals.php on line 38

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'   (include_path='.;D:\vFabricWS\vfabric-web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs/library/;D:\vFabricWS\vfabric- web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs/library/Doctrine/;D:\vFabricWS\vfabric-web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs/library/Braishfield/;D:\vFabricWS\vfabric-web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs/application/;D:\vFabricWS\vfabric-web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs/application/default/models/;D:\vFabricWS\vfabric-web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs/application/default/forms/') in D:\vFabricWS\vfabric-web-server\ProductionApp\htdocs\globals.php on line 38
```

****This is the main global data configuration file I'm using:**

```
//Define root path
//define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));

//Modify include path to include path to libraries and application folders
ini_set('include_path', '.' . 
    PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_PATH . '/library/' . 
    PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_PATH . '/library/Doctrine/' .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_PATH . '/library/CompanyName/' .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_PATH . '/application/'  . 
    PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_PATH . '/application/default/models/'  . 
    PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_PATH . '/application/default/forms/'
    );

//Include Loader File, and Load needed Classes
//require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
require_once '/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

//Load some config files and store them in the Registry for the rest of the
//app to access
if (! defined( 'UNIT_TESTING' ))
{
   $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_PATH . '/config/config.ini', 'application');
}
 else
{
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_PATH . '/config/config.ini', 'application');
}



Zend_Registry::set('config',$config);


//turn error reporting on if the debug flag is set in teh config file
$logger = new Zend_Log();
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);

if($config->debug)
{
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
$writer->setEnabled(true);

}
 else 
{
  ini_set('display_errors','off');
$writer->setEnabled(false);

}

ini_set('log_errors','on');
ini_set('error_log',ROOT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'logs/phperrors.log');

//Set mssql text sizes
ini_set("mssql.textlimit", "65536");
ini_set("mssql.textsize", "65536");

//set default time zone for the application
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your application does not use Zend Framework version 2. It uses version 1, and the two are completely incompatible, apart from using the same idioms and modules most of the time, because the version 2 uses PHP namespaces, and version 1 does not.

If you want to upgrade from 1 to 2, this is a major refactoring task, and probably way beyond your level of ability if you are not a programmer.

The other thing is: Don't look at the documentation for version 2.1 (which is mentioned in your link) if you are using version 2.2.

The latest version of version 1 is 1.12.3, but be careful not to destroy your application by upgrading to this version, because there are sometimes incompatible changes introduced in the steps between the minor versions. So an update will still be some adventure if you don't have a solid test suite that checks every part of the software.